# Move referenced document in separate collection into original collection mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have an existing collection that references another collection which is then populated when querying the database. I have changed my mind and would now just like to embed those documents in the original collection. Is there a way to do this programatically?

Here is what I have:

```
events: [{
  _id '38e88a8c8323...',
  items: [
    { ObjectID: '5e0f39e0d90a09c...'}
  ]
}]
items: [{
  _id: '5e0f39e0d90a09c...',
  name: 'Example'
}]
```

Here is what I want:

```
events: [{
  _id '38e88a8c8323...',
  items: [
     {
        _id: '5e0f39e0d90a09c...',
        name: 'Example'
     }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may perform aggegation with `$unwind` and `$lookup` pipeline.

```
db.events.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$items"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "items",
      localField: "items.ObjectID",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "items"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      items: {
        $push: {
          $arrayElemAt: [
            "$items",
            0
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $merge:{
      into : "tmp",
      on : "_id", 
      whenMatched : "replace",
      whenNotMatched : "insert"
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SJnHkrtgVh1)

**EDIT:** It will create `tmp` collection. Just drop `events` and rename `tmp` to `events`.

Comment: Thanks but I'd like to actually save it that way to the database then remove the items collection (because they are embedded in the events collection)

Comment: I've updated. You can add [$merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/) as last pipeline and insert result into tmp collection

Answer (score 0):

FWIW I ended up using $lookup and $out since $merge wasn't available in the version of Mongodb I was using ($merge is available at v4.2).

```
db.events.aggregate([
  {'$lookup': {
       'from':'items', 
       'localField':'items',
       'foreignField':'_id',
       'as':'items'
  }},{'$out':'events'}])
```

This saved it directly to events so I didn't have to create a temporary collection and rename